# Pytest how to have patch for a function from fixture

Tags: pytest

i am patching a function from a class. when i directly patch the function in my test code it works, but if i create a fixture and then patch (same function), then my test doesn't work (patch function is not called, but the actual function is called.)

How can i patch from a fixture?

below works

```
#path directly on test method works
@patch('a.b.MyClass.myFunction')
def test_mypoc(mock_MyClass):
        mock_MyClassFromFixture.returnValue = "dummy"
```

Below doesn't work (trying to patch from a fixture, so that can be reused across multiple test functions)

```
#patch on a fixture
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module")
@patch('a.b.MyClass.myFunction')
def mock_MyClassFromFixture(mock_MyClass):
    return mock_MyClass

#test code
def test_mypoc(mock_MyClassFromFixture):
    mock_MyClassFromFixture.returnValue = "dummy"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `pytest` you can stay directly within the `pytest` ecosphere and use [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html) for  a problem like this.

Given the following class:

```
class MyClass:
    def fizz(self):
        return "foo"
```

We can modify the test to run as such:

```
import pytest

from src.foo import MyClass


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_MyClassFromFixture(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(MyClass, "fizz", lambda x: "buzz")


def test_MyClass():
    klass = MyClass()
    assert klass.fizz() == "buzz"
```

Several things to note, `monkeypatch` is a `function` scoped fixture so it can't be used across the module unless you take the approach mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1872#issuecomment-375108891), and since you mention that it is a function you are trying to patch, the returned object should be callable, hence the use of `lambda`. We could have also declared a function within the test instead of using `lambda`, but that is entirely up to you.

Comment: If you prefer the API of `mock.patch`, the plugin [`pytest-mock`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) provides a `mocker` fixture which has a lot more power and flexibility than the `monkeypatch` fixture affords.

Comment: yes, if you are unopposed to adding another 3rd party dependency I highly suggest using the plugin that @wim mentions

Answer (score 0):

No need for a dependency or `monkeypatch` according to my experiment.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def some_fixture(tmpdir):
    mock_process = mock.Mock()
    mock_process.returncode = 0 # mock successful return
    with mock.patch('subprocess.run', return_value=mock_process) as mock_run:
        tmpdir.mock_run = mock_run # cheeky, but seems to work
        yield
```

in the test:

```
def test_mytest(tmpdir):
    my_object.do_something() # this involves calling subprocess.run(...)
    tmpdir.mock_run.assert_called_once()
```

... it thus appears that only one `tmpdir` fixture is created, and you can stick the name of a patch on it like sticking the tail on a donkey.

I don't know whether you can use *any* fixture to smuggle in a patch like this. It has a slight downside, in that it is potentially puzzling to a maintainer see `tmpdir.mock_run`.

You could also attach this object to `mock`, for example: `mock.mock_run = mock_run`. The danger there is that that might persist after the test. But that's easily solved:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def some_fixture(tmpdir):
    mock_process = mock.Mock()
    mock_process.returncode = 0 
    with mock.patch('subprocess.run', return_value=mock_process) as mock_run:
        mock.mock_run = mock_run 
        yield
     del mock.mock_run
```